# How to search listbox items with only part of its text

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox-control

I have a C# WinForms application. There is a listbox filled with values in this format:

```
category:user:id
Food:tester:17
```

etc.

Now, I need to get if an item is included in this Listbox, knowing only the category and ID, I don't know the user. So technically, I need to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
if(MyListBox.Items.Contains("Food:*:17"))
```

where the * would mean "anything". Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the listbox is filled directly with strings, the easiest way would be a combination of linq and regex:

```
 if(MyListBox.Items.Cast<string>().Any(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, "Food:.*:17")))  //(For RegEx: using System.Text.RegularExpressions )
```

or more strict, if the items are always a combination of value:value:value and you only check the first and third value:

```
if (MyListBox.Items.Cast<string>().Any(s => { var values = s.Split(':'); return values[0] == "Food" && values[2] == "17"; }))
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like  this

```
var res =
               MyListBox.items.SingleOrDefault(
                    item =>
                    item.Contains("Food:") && item.Contains(":17") &&
                    item.IndexOf(":17", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) >
                    item.IndexOf("Food:", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
                if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(res))
            {
              //your code here 
            }



            }
```

Comment: That would mean I get "true" if there is any food, and any ID 17, I need it to be both in one item

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
var value = MyListBox.Items.Cast<string>()
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Contains("Food:") && m.Contains(":17"));
if (value != null) {
    // you have a match
}
```